# Como vetorizar código em C++?

Tags: c++, compilação, otimização, gcc

Gostaria de saber como vetorizar código em C++ ? pois o material que encontrei na internet é um pouco excasso em relação a isso.

Entendo como vetorização a utilização, não somente de vetores, mas sim de fazer em um único passo todo uma sequência de passos, ou seja, fazer de uma só vez  `d= (c+e)/2;`   em vez de ficar repetindo esses passo para cada posição da matriz   `d[i][j] = (c[i][j]+e[i][j])/2;`

Por exemplo como vetorizar o programa a seguir ?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(){

    int d[4][4],c[4][4],e[4][4];

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
            c[i][j] =i+j;
            e[i][j] = 4*i;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
            d[i][j] = (c[i][j]+e[i][j])/2;
            if(d[i][j]<3){
                d[i][j]=3;
            } 
        }  
    }
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
           cout << d[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Quando eu uso a flag de vetorização para ver quantos loops estão sendo vetorizado com a ajuda da `-O2 -ftree-vectorize -fopt-info-vec-optimized`  ele me responde " loop vetorized " ou seja somente um loop foi vetorizado e se eu usar a -all em vez da `-optimized` ele me retorna que muitas partes do programa não foi vetorizado.

Comment: O que você chama de vetorizar código? Esse conceito de vetorização para mim só se aplica a geometria analítica e áreas afim

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Vetorização é usar as instruções SIMD para realizar operações em paralelo. Por exemplo, quando for somar dois vetores, normalmente vc faz a soma em cada componente do vetor, separadamente. Com SIMD, vc pode somar todos os componentes, simultaneamente https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_vectorization

Comment: Não entendi a sua pergunta. Veja no [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8ac89ac9178d7d6) Tem 2 loops vetorizados

Comment: @Amadeus a pergunta é voltada principalmente para como vetorizar loops que tenham estruturas condicionais. Não sei qual versão do g++ você está usando mas aqui realmente só vetoriza 1 loop o dá inicialização, não sendo vetorizado o que possui o condicional if e o que chamada do sistema para printar os valores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que o condicional `if` contido dentro do segundo *loop* não permite que ele seja otimizado pelo compilador:

```
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
        d[i][j] = (c[i][j]+e[i][j])/2;
        if(d[i][j]<3){
            d[i][j]=3;
        }
    }
}
```

Uma solução para esse problema é a substituição do condicional `if` por um condicional `ternário`, por exemplo:

```
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
        d[i][j] = (c[i][j]+e[i][j])/2;
        d[i][j] = ( d[i][j] < 3 ) ? 3 : d[i][j];
    }
}
```

Teste de Compilação `GCC`:

```
$ g++ -v -O2 -ftree-vectorize -fopt-info-vec-optimized vect.cpp -o vect
```

Saída:

```
[...]

Analyzing loop at vect.cpp:21

Analyzing loop at vect.cpp:14

vect.cpp:14: note: vect_recog_divmod_pattern: detected: 
vect.cpp:14: note: pattern recognized: patt_3 = patt_4 >> 1;

Analyzing loop at vect.cpp:15

vect.cpp:15: note: vect_recog_divmod_pattern: detected: 
vect.cpp:15: note: pattern recognized: patt_77 = patt_1 >> 1;


Vectorizing loop at vect.cpp:15

vect.cpp:15: note: LOOP VECTORIZED.
Analyzing loop at vect.cpp:8

Analyzing loop at vect.cpp:9


Vectorizing loop at vect.cpp:9

vect.cpp:9: note: LOOP VECTORIZED.
vect.cpp:4: note: vectorized 2 loops in function.

[...]
```

Referências:

https://locklessinc.com/articles/vectorize/

https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/tree-ssa/vectorization.html

**EDIT:**

A resposta se aplica somente a versão `4.8` do `GCC`.

A versão `7.0`, já e capaz de vetorizar loops sem a necessidade de substituir os condicionais `if` por operadores ternários através da opção de otimização `-fsplit-loops`.

Referência: https://clearlinux.org/blogs/gcc-7-importance-cutting-edge-compiler

Comment: Não responde a pergunta original. Já se tinha 2 loops vetorizados, não mudou nada com a sua proposta [Original no coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8ac89ac9178d7d6)

Comment: @Amadeus: A pergunta menciona que **apenas um** loop foi otimizado. Minha resposta explica a razão e apresenta uma solução para a otimização dos dois loops. Repare bem.

Comment: @Amadeus:  O seu exemplo no coliru utiliza o `GCC 7.2.0`, e com certeza, ela já 'sabe' vetorizar loops com condicionais sem utilizar operadores ternários. Em versões mais antigas, tais como a 4.8, isso parece não acontecer.

Comment: @Lacobus perfeito, era isso mesmo .Agora vetoriza o loop com condicional.